# Vi editor on mac, and cheatsheet

Tags: editor, vi

I'm using mac, and I'm in search for a new free editor to use. I'm familiar with vi from college days a bit rusty with the Vi commands.

Can someone tell me, what is a good free vi editor to use on a mac, and a good link to top vi commands?

Answer (score 0):

type `brew install macvim` into a terminal (or install macvim some other way)

This will install macvim on your computer, which you can now use by typing `vim` in a terminal.

type `vimtutor` in a terminal to start a guide on how to use vim,
or whilst inside vim, type `:e /usr/share/vim/vim74/tutor/tutor` to open to open the guide.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using NeoVim as I'm daily using it. Because of:

- Simplify maintenance and encourage contributions
- Split the work between multiple developers
- Enable advanced UIs without modifications to the core
- Maximize extensibility

I think NeoVim is the most active project which bases on Vim and it is free for sure: https://github.com/neovim/neovim

For the tutorial, the easiest way is type `vimtutor` on the terminal, all the commands you need are there.